ImportError: cannot import name 'UMAP' from 'umap' (unknown location)
I'm currently working on converting Word2Vec embedding to PubMedBERT embedding. I am working in Google Colab, and I'm running into the issue where: ImportError: cannot import name 'UMAP' from 'umap' (unknown location) keeps popping up even though I've uninstalled bertopic and reinstalled it.
from bertopic import BERTopic
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
from umap import UMAP

docs = abstracts
sentence_model = SentenceTransformer("neuml/pubmedbert-base-embeddings")
embeddings = sentence_model.encode(docs, show_progress_bar = False)

topic_model = BERTopic()
topics, probs = topic_model.fit_transform(docs, embeddings = embeddings)

topic_model.visualize_documents(docs, embeddings = embeddings)

^is my code cell.
I've also uninstalled umap and reinstalled it. I read online that I need to restart the runtime, which I did, but it seems that I cannot get umap to get imported correctly. I've triied restarting the runtime, uninstalling and reinstalling bertopic, sentence_transformers, and umap. Are there any potential issues outside of this cell?

How are you installing umap?

just !pip install umap. but apparently it's been solved? so there's that i guess lol thank you!
